# Show hidden image on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mapping, area

I have a problem when trying achieve hover effect on mapped image. I have an image with mapped areas and on all of them I want to show a different image when hover.

You can see my work so far here:

http://mantasmilka.com/map/pries-smurta.html

The problem is when I hover over area it show the image, but when I move the cursor (not leaving the area) it starts flickering. It takes area space pixel by pixel.

I've tried working with Javascript and jQuery solutions:

Javascript:

```
mouseenter="document.getElementById('Vilnius').style.display = 'block';" mouseleave="document.getElementById('Vilnius').style.display = 'none';"
```

jQuery:

```
$('.hide').hide();
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#area-kaunas").mouseenter(function(){
        $('#Kaunas').show();
    });
    $("#area-kaunas").mouseleave(function(){
        $('#Kaunas').hide();
    });
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a css property called "pointer-event" which gives the value "none" to the img tags that overlap in the mapped image and works as you need it. This is the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

The problem will always be the compatibility of browsers.

Comment: This was the solution! Thank you, I forgot about the image over the area. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) inside of jQuery? I'm also unsure why you bind the events after a 500 millisecond timeout?

```
$('.hide').hide();

$("#area-kaunas").hover(function() {
    $('#Kaunas').show();
}, function() {
    $('#Kaunas').hide();
});
```

Comment: I was trying out delay, because I thought that maybe it does hoverout and hover in every pixel. But the soluton with point-events none does the trick. I didn't think of images overlaping my main hover area and so causing the flicker. Your hover code as well is a bit better solution.